# Checar se outra Aplicação esta viva

Tags: android

Tenho uma aplicação que fica rodando 24h por dia gerando alguns dados, e ela costumava travar de tempos em tempos quando precisava enviar os dados para um servidor web. Então veio a ideia de desmembrar em duas apps, uma gera os dados e outra transmite.

A duvida é a seguinte, a cada ciclo da app "principal", após gerar os dados, ela inicializa a app secundária para transmitir os dados, como eu posso checar se essa segunda aplicação está viva do ciclo passado e como mata-la caso estiver antes de chama-la novamente?

Comment: Para enviar os dados use um [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).